# How do I sort the values of this array?

Tags: javascript

I know how or I thought I knew how sort worked in javascript. I know that by returning a-b, my array will be sorted ascending order.

However what is happening with this code, why do I not get the array in ascening order, instead I get the following

```
          var q = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

         q.sort((a,b)=>{return -1});
         [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation:

By default, a `sort ()` function does javascript in a lexical order in your Array. However, you can optionally pass a function in the input parameter, so that it returns the desired result.

### About a sort () function:

> ** sort ** ([* sort function *] **) **

> ** Description: ** sort an array lexically by default, but a function can be passed for sorting.

> #### Parameters:

> ** sortFunction ** (function) * optional *:

> A function that returns the order needed to be used in `sort ()`.

#Example:

```js
    function sortfunction(a, b){
  return (a - b) //faz com que o array seja ordenado numericamente e de ordem crescente.
}
Data = [3,5,1,7,3,9,10];
alert(Data.sort(sortfunction));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a utility function

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}
let q = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

q.sort(compareNumbers)
var q = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  // [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

To sort in ascending order subtract b from a